# How to wrap an HtmlElement in an HtmlDocument

Tags: html, .net, powershell

Is it possible to wrap an HtmlElement with another HtmlElement? And if so, how?

Lets say, I have this HTML, and I want to wrap the `img` with an additional `div`:

```
<html>
  <head><title>foo</title></head>
  <body>
    <img src="test.png"/>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried using following snippet (n.b. document element is an [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
$htmlFile = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$htmlFile.IHtmlDocument2_write((gc -Path "./html.htm" -Raw))
$htmlFile.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("img") | %{
  $div = $htmlFile.createElement("div")
  $div.className += "nonbreakingImage"
  $void = $div.appendChild($_)
  $_.OuterHtml = $div.OuterHtml
}
```

But this, unfortunately, just removes the image tag:

```
<BODY><P>Hello World</P></BODY>
```

Another Idea was, to do something like this:

```
$htmlFile = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$htmlFile.IHtmlDocument2_write((gc -Path "./html.htm" -Raw))
$htmlFile.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("img") | %{
  $parent = $_.parentNode
  $void = $parent.removeChild($_)
  $div = $parent.appendChild($htmlFile.createElement("div"))
  $div.className += " nonbreakingImage"
  $void = $div.appendChild($_)
}
```

But that leaves me with a wrong child order:

```
<BODY>
  <P>Hello World</P>
  <DIV class=" nonbreakingImage"><IMG src="test.png"></DIV>
</BODY>
```

Any ideas and hints are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *replace* `<img>` node with a `<div>` node then add (now floating) `<img>` node to newly added `<div>`. In code:

```
$htmlFile.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("img") | %{
  $div = $htmlFile.createElement("div")
  $div.className += " nonbreakingImage"

  $_.parentNode.replaceChild($div, $_)
  $div.appendChild($_)
}
```

In alternative you may `$_.insertBefore($div, ...)` of node obtained by `$_.previousSibling(...)` but it's longer.